# How do I keep hard-boiled eggs from turning green near the yolk?

Tags: eggs, hard-boiled-eggs

How do I keep them from turning green yolk? Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe not worded quite the same, but see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6366/67

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate…

Comment: I guess that’s technically the reverse of your question (what causes it) vs. how to prevent it, which has more potential answers, although they’re all basically ‘don’t overcook it’, just different in how they might achieve it

Comment: Hi Joshua, if you believe that your question is not a duplicate, then please edit it such that the difference between this one and the old one is obviously clear. Reopening of closed questions is certainly possible, but it has to be clear that the reason for their closure no longer applies. If you want to know something other than what the poster of the old question wanted to know, you have to make it clear - as it stands, it seems that you only want to know how to prevent green yolks, which is already clearly asked in the old question.

Comment: @rumtscho I have no idea what your obsession with closing questions is, but as they’re asking for the correct way to cook hard boiled eggs, they’re closer to https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/714/67 .  But that’s not what they asked, as some of them may risk green rings.  Just because a question may be answered indirectly by another question does NOT make it a duplicate

Comment: @Joe The older questions asks literally "how do I prevent it", and the existing answers address the prevention part. I know that we sometimes have pairs of questions where one asks about the theoretical explanation of a phenomenon and the other asks how to stop it from happening (or how to achieve it, depending on what it is) and I don't see those as duplicates. In this case, the older question is explicit about including the prevention topic. I have difficulty seeing why an answer to the question here would not fit under the older question.

Comment: If you mark this as a duplicate, it should be of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/714/67 , I don’t really think this is a duplicate though.

Comment: @Joshua could you please help me understand why it is not a duplicate? The way I interpret your question, you want to prevent the yolk of hardboiled eggs from getting a green layer. Is this wrong? What is it that you want to know?